# Hibernate - JPA fetch query takes long time to finish

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 different calls I make using JPA and Hibernate. The first call takes lots of time to execute (about 5 minutes) and it is fetching only one object, this is a custom query made on the JPA repo.

The second one fetches a list of the same object mentioned above in about 10 seconds.

First query:

```
Optional<MachineGroupToVersion> omgtv = machineGroupToVersionService.getByVersionNameAndMachineGroupId(versionName, machineGroupId);

 public Optional<MachineGroupToVersion> getByVersionNameAndMachineGroupId(String versionName, long machineGroupId) {
        return machineGroupToVersionRepository.findByVersionNameAndMachineGroupId(versionName, machineGroupId);
    }
```

Second query:

```
List<MachineGroupToVersion> omgtv = machineGroupToVersionService.getByMachineGroupName(machineGroupName);

 public List<MachineGroupToVersion> getByMachineGroupName(String mgName) {

        List<MachineGroupToVersion> mgtvl = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional<MachineGroup> mg = machineGroupService.getByName(mgName);
        if(mg.isPresent()){
            mgtvl = machineGroupToVersionRepository.findByMachineGroup(mg.get());
        }
        return mgtvl;
    }
```

MachineGroupToVersion class

```
public class MachineGroupToVersion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "machine_groups_to_versions_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "machine_groups_to_versions_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id", nullable = false)
    private MachineGroup machineGroup;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id", nullable = false)
    private Version version;
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "tested_time")
    private Date testedTime;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Date creationTime;
}
```

What I can't understand is this: How fetching a single object takes significantly longer to execute then fetching a list of the same object?

I should mention that within the MachineGroupToVersion class most of the field are fetched EAGERLY, while I know this is what causing the query to execute slow, I am trying to figure out why fetching 1 object is slower then list of objects.

Comment: Enable the `show_sql` feature in hibernate and you'll see what queries are taking too long and where it gets stuck. It could easily be a problem in which the table `machine group to version` is not indexed properly for the first query but it's for the second so the DB ends up doing a full table scan. Also depends if you have a 2nd level cache configured.

Comment: +1 to what Augusto writes... I have seen projects were a single query would fetch the entire DB hierarchy, I really think you should start marking relations as lazy! By the way, `getByMachineGroupName` can be written as: `return machineGroupService.getByName(mgName).map(machineGroupToVersionRepository::findByMachineGroup).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);`

Comment: Thank you both! I will do the check and update accordingly. @NikosParaskevopoulos regarding the LAZY fetching I would be happy to do so but this is a big project in my company and I just started working on it so I don't know what would be the implications of changing this, as it can break other things :(

Comment: When I changed to LAZY fetching the 5 minute query took a few seconds so I know fetching EAGERLY is not good but changing it now can lead to other issues

Comment: I feel you... But you have a powerful weapon in your hands to make a case to the company, 5min to few seconds is a huge improvement. If not, I have seen a *very dirty* solution where there is a second entity mapped to the same table; the second entity is not updatable/insertable and has different mapping characteristics. That's awful though... another way to go, a bit more complex but may pay out (or not, depending on the exact case), is to run this specific query using entity graphs to limit the fetched data.

Comment: Yeah I might start changing things if I see that this is a recurring issue. I read about the Entity Graph and @JsonManagedReference before and I went with the JSON solution which did not work properly I guess I missed a few steps there. I will check that graph thingy too. Thank you!